# Vimeo iframe is causing a flicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, flicker

I have a site, with an embeded vimeo iframe. The page flickers when it loads, even more so in Chrome, and then again on your initial hover over the video. I was wondering if the iframe could be causing this. I fI remove it doesn't happen. If I leave and remove my javascripts it still happens. So I'm wondering if anyone has had experience with this.

this is the iframe code

```
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/85534169?byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="508" height="286" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

thanks

the site is currently live http://www.miltonkarate.com

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem : iframe with html5 video into another iframe cause the page flickering. only in chrome, others browser works well.

Remove your frameset in your website to fix the problem : 
http://bokushucom.ipage.com/Miltonkarate/

this works well without clicking